# Accessing a returned value from openCV function C++ NDK

Tags: c++, opencv, android-ndk

I am using the Knn findNearest function in OpenCV, which takes in the following parameters:

```
Mat response;
Mat dist;

knn->findNearest(testFeature, K, noArray(), response, dist);
```

The output returned from response and dist is of type OutputArray.

How do I access the results of response and dist in this format?
Ideally I would like to convert to Mat int.

Comment: you can put mat data into cpp array and then send it via jni array

Comment: How do I do this? I can't find any documentation for putting an OutputArray into a cpp array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610045/how-to-return-an-array-from-jni-to-java. this may helps

Comment: This doesn't help I'm afraid. Would you be able to give an example of what you said to do in your first answer?  How do I get the mat data into a cpp array?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the mat data into cpp array you can do like this.
I assume the Mat data you want to return is of float type.

```
int size=response.rows*response.cols*resonse.channels();
float* outArr=new float[size];
std::memcpy(outArr,response.data,size*sizeof(float));
```

you need to delete outArr after copying it to JNIArray.